# HOW to find a specific record from column

Tags: postgresql-9.5

If my column has record like this:

```
"0,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative"
```

and column data type is **text**.

How can I find a record **<7** (less than seven) from that column.

If i use `cast(substring(p.result,1,2) as float) <7` then this error is occurred:

> invalid input syntax for type double precision: "  "

and for int this ERROR:

> invalid input syntax for integer: "9."

So, I am stuck in there, how to do it.

Query

```
select * from dg_result_entry_header h
inner join dg_result_entry_detail p 
     on h.result_entry_id = p.result_entry_id
where p.sub_investigation_id = 243 
      and h.result_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-30' 
      and cast(substring(p.result,1,2) as int) <7
      and p.result is not null
```

current table structure

[image: Current Table Structure]

i want only <7 count from result column and output like this

count <7

121

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: @McNets: Actually lab result stored in that column and i have to find a HB record >=0 and  < 7 but column has int,float,char everything data is present.

Comment: It is a comma-separated value list. Are you looking for the first element of that list?

Comment: @McNets : Just i am trying that, if possible. I had try lots of thing but cant't find any proper solution for that. 0,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative each record present in separate row and from that i wanna just < 7 records those are int.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table tbl (val text);
> insert into tbl values 
> ('0,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,'',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative'),
> ('9,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,'',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative'),
> ('3,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,'',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative'),
> ('8,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,'',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative');
> ```

You can get first element of the list using **[string_to_array()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)** function.

> ```
> select (string_to_array(val, ','))[1] from   tbl
> ```
>
> ```
> | string_to_array |
> | :-------------- |
> | 0               |
> | 9               |
> | 3               |
> | 8               |
> ```

Or filter rows using a cast in this way:

```
(string_to_array(val, ','))[1]::int < 7
```

> ```
> select *
> from   tbl
> where  (string_to_array(val, ','))[1]::int < 7
> ```
>
> ```
> | val                                                         |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 0,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative |
> | 3,11.2,2,5,1-2,1,SAMPLE CLOT,',11.2 g/dl,14300,145,negative |
> ```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=64fa980bbe3fa197d9e68b7c4d9db443)*</kbd>